# Yii2 debug toolbar local time config

Tags: debugging, yii2, toolbar

I would like to get the real Time in the Debug Toolbar Logging panel but actually the Time is showing one hour less :
for example:

```
2021-01-06 03:52:27 pm and here time is 04:52:27 pm
```

I couldn't find any config for this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the timezone in the `config/web.php` (*if yii2-basic*) or `common/config/main.php` (*if using yii2-advanceapp*) like below, i am using my specific timezone in the example

```
<?php
return [
    'timeZone' => 'Asia/Karachi',
];
```

[image]